# Android Studio crashes with bluetooth getSystemService call. May be gradle/api version related

Tags: android, gradle, bluetooth

I am making an app that uses BLE and I am trying to get basic functionality for streaming Bluetooth data working on my app. However, this line:

```
BluetoothManager btManager =(BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
```

will crash my app upon initialization.

The app works fine without this call on my phone as far as fragments and the navigation drawer goes.

I thought there could be something wrong with my SDK versions and my phone (test phone is android 7.0) so I changed my SDK version from 8.0 to 7.0 and by build tools to the latest 24 from 27. I got 15 errors which included ColorErrors and others when attempting Gradle build. It also said that my current version of Gradle was too new to run back at that API.

I set my minimum API to 21 Lollipop, but it seems to me that the Gradle version should be backward compatible that far at least. Do I have to start completely over with a new Gradle and set my target API to the lowest possible, or is there a way to salvage this?

Comment: what is the error when app crashes?

Comment: There is no debug error message, and on the app it just says "App has stopped working"

Comment: Depending on how you deployed your application (run/debug) you should be able to get the application log in Run/Debug console windows in Android Studio (bottom panel). Remember not to disconnect your phone from computer, because it will disable logging in Android Studio.

Comment: I was looking under the debug tab, and that had no useful info. I switched to the Logcat tab and found that my  bluetooth adapter call had to be in onCreate.